# Dynamic Template (Component) Probs to Class Binding Issue using Vue Js

Tags: javascript, html, vue-component, vue.js

I try to make dynamic template to assign the class by condition base.

My Template is :

```
<template v-if="showTemplate" id="campaignBlock">
   <div v-class="@{{ block_class }}">
// <div v-class="{ block_class }">
     <img src="{{URL::asset('uploads/default.png')}}">
  </div>
```

Template Call :

```
<input type="button" @click="nb += 1" class="btn btn-default" value="Add New Section">
<div v-for="a in nb">
   <block v-if="nb == 4" block_class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"></block>
   <block v-if="nb == 3" block_class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"></block>
   <block v-if="nb == 2" block_class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"></block>
   <block v-if="nb == 1" block_class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"></block>
</div>
```

VueJs :

```
 Vue.component('block', {
   template: '#campaignBlock',
   props: ['block_class'],
   data: function () {
       return {
           n: 0,
           nb: 1,
           block_class: 'col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6'
        }
    }
});
```

Here, if I increase the columns, then I get expected props value in template as a variable.

ex. `<div v-class="{{ block_class }}">`

But, if I try to assign in a "class", just present as text. Also I tried native class too. I can't pass the `pros(block_class)` to the template.

Any possible way to handle this issue?

I'm using Laravel.

Comment: When adding HTML snippets inline in your questions, they must be `surrounded by backticks` so as to become visible. Please always read your questions through using the preview feature before posting, so as to save the time of editors, and to make it clear what you are asking. Furthermore, do not request urgency or any special treatment - volunteers may get around to your questions at their leisure.

Comment: Oh...Sorry, actually i just repast here from the forum ...
I forget to remove that "word" ....
Thanks for noticing !

Comment: If this is pasted elsewhere, would you add the link where you have cross-posted it? It is good to do that in the first instance, so that helpful people who answer do not accidentally duplicate help you have received in another place.

Comment: Yah... Understand !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dynamic styling](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) for doing this,

You may pass a object hash in props to the component like following:

```
<input type="button" @click="nb += 1" class="btn btn-default" value="Add New Section">
<div v-for="a in nb">
   <block v-if="nb == 4" block_class="{'col-md-3': true, 'col-sm-6': true, 'col-xs-6': true"></block>
</div>
```

and in the template code:

```
<template v-if="showTemplate" id="campaignBlock">
   <div :class="block_class">
// <div :class="block_class">
     <img src="{{URL::asset('uploads/default.png')}}">
  </div>
```

Comment: And what abt removing element in vueJs...?

Comment: @ShankarThiyagaraajan Can you elaborate more on that, v-if or v-show should able to help. Also is it is not related to this question, you can accept this answer and ask another question with relevant details.

Comment: In jquery, we can use simply, "jQuery(this).closest('.parent_class).remove();"
 But in vue js, how could we perform similar action ?